# tabbar custom images for iphone / ipad selection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

I am working on customizing my tabbar background image and i resolved this for iphone by customizing tabbar class. it looks like that:

[image]

Then same thing i put for my ipad app it looks like that

[image]

I need the tab bar without extra spaces or black color in the image above. so i tried to update the tabbar class for ipad as well and i reached to this image below:

[image]

I managed the tabbar button views without extra spaces but unable to manage its button selection area, how can i manage the tabbar button selection ? it is still the same as second image, you can see the highlight of "settings" tabbar button selection in "Transaction" tabbar button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UITabBarController cannot work as you would like it to.  You should write your own UITabBarController class - see this for an example of how: https://github.com/aalittle/ALCustomTabBarController

Comment: Can any one have answer i am looking for the same.

Comment: @dacopenhagen I conevrted that for ipad and yes your link helped alot,thanks